# ¿Cual es la función principal de util.promisify?

Tags: nodejs

He estado buscando algunos ejemplos de como usar util.promisify en Node.JS pero no me queda claro el cómo funciona. ¿Tendrán algún ejemplo sencillo de como y cuando ocuparlo? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Promisify incluye el nuevo API **utils.promisify()** que permite envolver el API de callbacks estándar de Node.js para usar promesas.

Por ejemplo:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

readFile('/algun/archivo')
    .then(data => { /** ... **/ })
    .catch(err => { /** ... **/ });
```

si observas en el ejemplo utilizado promisify no tenes que declarar then y catch.

Answer (score 0):

Sirve para declarar "promises", el cual es un tipo de objeto que se usa en comunicaciones asincronas.

Con esto lo que se define es la promesa de que hay "algo" que retornará esa comunicación, y qué sucederá en caso de que funcione correctamente (accept) y qué sucederá en caso de que no funcione correctamente (reject).

Aquí tienes más info: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise